# error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 11 while clean build JSF web application

Tags: java

I'm trying to run simple JSF application (Java web) of sending data from one page to another when button is clicked using JDK 11.0.4 and apache netbeans 12.1 in windows. When i clean build project it shows 'error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 11'

JSF framework version

1. managed bean

```
package model;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named(value = "bean1")
@RequestScoped
public class bean1 {

    String nm;

    public String getNm() {
        return nm;
    }

    public void setNm(String nm) {
        this.nm = nm;
    }
    
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of bean1
     */
    public bean1() {
    }
    
}
```

2. page1.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Page 1</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h2>Hello Page 1</h2>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="txtName"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="txtName" value="#{bean1.nm}" />
            #{bean1.nm}
            <h:commandButton value="SEND" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

3.page2.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Page2</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        #{bean1.nm}
    </h:body>
</html>
```

4.web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

5.faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.3"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

still it gets deployed and run , after running on browser following error is coming when i click on button
[page1.xhtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z3OK.png)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKgAz.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved after creating a new java web application with new project name .Keep this in mind ,don't use same name as provided to your current project
eg : if my this project name is JSFDemo then new project name should be other than JSFDemo
only
Hence Solved:)